# need to improve performance of spark-sql joins

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I have been working on a project where we are using spark-sql as analytic platform and currently I am facing issues while joining two data frames `df1` & `df2`

`df1` has 25000 records
`df2` has 127000 records

When I am joining these two tables in spark-dataframe it is taking lot of time to join

> val df_join = df1.join(df2, df2("col1") ===
>   df1("col1")).drop(df1("col2"))

I checked the Spark-UI for status and it is showing some astonishing numbers
and input size/records are increasing weirdly

Kindly let me know why and how input size is increasing considerably and how should i tune my spark job

attached are the screen shot of cluster
3 node cluster running on yarn
6 gb for driver
5 gb for executor allocated and 2 cores per executor

[image]

[image]

Status of job after more than 30 mins, input size has increased to almost 1000GB
[image]